# Increase disk size on Microsoft Azure

Tags: ubuntu, azure, storage, azure-storage, azure-devops

I am new in Microsoft Azure. I saw the Azure docs and there's showing that we can only increase the disk size while the virtual machine de-allocate/stopped. But for the production it is not possible to stop my virtual machine. I am using Ubuntu virtual machine. So is there any way to increase disk size on Azure virtual machine without stopping it or on the fly ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, this not possible on GCP or Azure. You have to stop the VM.

I suggest you create a new one from a snapshot with a new size of disk and then turn off the old image